# Find max element in tree

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a binary tree which implements nodes this way:

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T>
{
    T element;
    BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChild;  // left subtree
    BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChild; // right subtree
}
```

And I'm trying to search the max value saved in the tree, but I've failed to create a successful method to achieve this. Here is what I've tried:

```
public void maxElement(Method visit)
{
    ArrayList<T> a = new ArrayList<>();
    BinaryTreeNode<T> b = root;

    while(b != null)
    {
        try
        {
            visit.invoke(null, b); //This visit Method is to traverse the nodes
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        if(b.leftChild != null)
            a.add(b.leftChild.element);
        if(b.rightChild != null)
            a.add(b.rightChild.element);

        Collections.sort(a); //Here is where it fails
        System.out.println(a.get(0));
    }
}
```

This is the error IDE throws:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList). The inferred type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

I know I'm failing trying to sort a generic type, but then don't know how to achive what I want.

Comment: Failing?? what is happening. Wrong output, exception anything?

Comment: @Prateek Updating with the error

Comment: Is this a [BinaryTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) or a [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Binary tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `T` is expected to be a type that supports comparison, then you should be declaring

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

which you should read as saying "Objects of type T must be comparable to other objects of type T."

Comment: I can't extend T that way. If I could, this would do it.

Comment: @JhonAlx Why not? How are you supposed to sort them if they can't be compared to each other?

Comment: Let's say the code my teacher uses for executing this won't have BinaryTreeNode<T extends Comparable<T>>. Maybe I will have to use my own implementation of BinaryTreeNode, extending it and then implmenting Comparable<T>

Comment: How do you compare the nodes if the values they hold aren't comparable?

Comment: Just figured out how to do it (using reflection)

public T maxElement(){
    if(this.root==null)return null; /
    return maxaux(root); 
}

static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T maxaux(BinaryTreeNode t){ 
 //Compare
}

Comment: Marking your answer as accepted because this inspired me to get to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue you can change the definition of `a` from
`ArrayList<T> a = new ArrayList<>();` to `List<T> a = new ArrayList<>();`

few side notes:

1. you should what @Louis Wasserman suggested - that has 0 affect on how your teacher will execute, what it merely means is `BinaryTreeNode<Integer>` is ok, but `BinaryTreeNode<Object>` for example is not. in other words you just limiting what T can be - this way its much cleaner and gives upfront info about elements
2. variable names are important, especially if you do school assignment, i got lost between `a` and `b` at first :(